# Why Doctrine2 doesn't automatically quote all SQL identifiers?

Tags: doctrine-orm

Doctrine manual says:

> Doctrine does not quote identifiers automatically because this leads
>   to more problems, than it would solve.

What exactly problems are there with quoting everything?

Answer (score 3):

This quote comes from an older version of the documentation, under the [Basic Mapping](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/basic-mapping.html) section. The latest documentation doesn't include this text anymore, *but it is still true*.

The [Limitations and Known Issues](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/limitations-and-known-issues.html#identifier-quoting-and-legacy-databases) section of the latest documentation sheds some light on this:

> For compatibility reasons between all the supported vendors and edge case problems Doctrine 2 does **NOT** do automatic identifier quoting.

Because of the different quoting strategies used in different SQL vendors, and the way SQL is generated by the ORM, it is quite hard to come up with a solution that works for all cases. And it's even harder to maintain. It might not be impossible, but the Doctrine team decided it isn't worth the time, and (perhaps more importantly) code complexity, to try.

For a hint on how complex SQL generation is, browse through the code in the [git repository](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/tree/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM).

It's a common best practice to only use alphanumeric characters (and underscores) for identifiers, and to *not* use reserved keywords. If you follow those, you won't need identifier quoting.

If you do need to, because your dealing with a legacy database, Doctrine offers 2 solutions:

1. Manual quoting of identifiers, see the [Basic Mapping](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/basic-mapping.html#quoting-reserved-words) section.
2. Create database views that follow the best practices mentioned earlier.

PS: For those who don't know: "identifier" does *not* refer to primary keys, but to the names of tables, columns, indexes, etc.

Comment: Thanks for an answer, but it didn't really answer my core question. Can you give me an example of how complex quoting identifiers is? I always thought that it is as simple as "take identifier of type X" (x= table, column, database name etc.) and "apply quoting strategy Q(X) to it" (usually just wrap into some kind of quotes). Isn't that so?

Comment: I think you can view it this way: Imagine you create the system you propose, supporting all DB vendors Doctrine supports. Now imagine integrating that system into Doctrine. Try to estimate the time and resources that would take. Is that worth the gain you get from having it?

Comment: BTW, the primary reason for that statement to be in the documentation is because not long ago there was a well published discussion: Most ORMs and the like state they are safe from SQL injection because of quoting. But most only quote values, not identifiers. That was found misleading. So many ORMs have updated their documentation to expressly mention they don't quote identifiers.

Comment: Yep, I understand. I can read manuals and I can image complexity etc. But still, the question was about examples. I just like to see them.